# Adding 2 fixed navbar at different postions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem I am getting is that I want the second navbar with class navbar2 to be also fixed in the div `class="col-xs-10"` itelf so that the content below it can be scrolled easily without moving the navbar 2. The other problem is that when the navbar2 is fixed then the width cannot be maintained on different sizes of screens. The working code is here https://jsfiddle.net/0sqk00Lw/4/ .. Can someone help.. Thanks in advance

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar1">
<div class="container">
    NAVBAR FIXED TOP
</div>
</nav>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color:blue">
    hello 
</div>

<div class="col-xs-10">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar2">
       <div class="container">
          NAVBAR FIXED TOP
       </div>
    </nav>
    <p>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    hello<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/h7fjtbhz/

All elements changed to 100% width and calculated height for the p tag

```
height:calc(100% - 100px);  // change 100px to height of remaining elements above the second navbar
```

Tell me if something has to be changed.

Comment: hey.. thanks man :) .. you solved it.. I am an idiot that i couldn't think of this simple solution..!!! :/

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar2{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#fed136;
}
```

if you set position to relative it can't be fixed. it needs position:fixed to be set. and then you have to position it in relation to the viewport (not the parent element)

Comment: the only problem i get after setting the postion fixed is that the navbar2 width have to be hardcoded again and again in different screen sizes.. it does'nt match to its parent by assigning width to 100%

Comment: it does not have parent. the parent is the viewport. otherways you need to change the position by javascript when onscroll event happens